# Weird behaviour on UItextview inside UItableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a static UItableview with some cells. Some cells are Uitextview, when I click on it, the screen will jump off or scroll to somewhere but not focus on the Uitextview. I have included the gif file on the weird behaviour for everyone to have a clearer look. Kindly guide me what is happening on this weird issue. Thanks guys

https://media.giphy.com/media/FDBphSmOojc4MKT48F/giphy.gif

Comment: How did you handled keyboard?

Comment: i am just using the library IQkeyboardmanager

Comment: @ChanOnly123 also this tableview is inside a container view which inside another static tableview cell. But I dont think this should be the issue right?

Comment: Keyboard handling is only responsible kind of behavior. So try to handle keyboard manually if no other solution works.